# Python script that takes xyz and returns the perspective matrix vertex coordinates

Tags: python, scripting, matrix, project

I've been trying to write a script that receives the **xyz coordinates of a vertex of a 3D object** and returns the **xyz coordinates of the vertex in a prespective projection plane**, more or less like in the following image:

[image]

Example:

```
get_prespective(3,4,8):
     bla...
     new_vector = [3,4,0]
     return new_vector
```

Supposedly you need to **multiply** the vector with a **prespective matrix**, like this:

[image]

Or multiplying the vector by this matrix:

[image]

But I'm having some trouble figuring out **which matrix** to use or **how** to use it. If somebody has a better idea, that would be great ;)